# Show custom error page on IIS side when site is stopped

Tags: asp.net, iis

Whenever site is stopped IIS shows this default 404-error page:
[image]

1. Is it possible to edit this page or replace on something fancy?
2. If so what is location of these error files?

Comment: https://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/

Comment: 2 VDWWD:
That article explains how to set up error pages on site level. So if site is stopped it would not work. I need settings on whole IIS server level.

Comment: There are, you can specify error pages on site and server level. But if you are talking about a 503 then you cannot specify it.

Comment: 2 VDWWD:
You mean site error pages on server level (i.e. no need to specify each site separately). But i mean IIS server error pages (not site) it responses to request. Site can not respond whatever if it switched off

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @user3172616 ?